# How Many Amps Is this breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, breaker-box

I am trying to figure out how many amps this box has. Top left breaker is 50amp and top right is 30amp. I want to put an xray machine on this that requires 100amps at its max. Do you think its possible?[image]

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question with only the information you've provided. Where do the thick wires at the top come from? What is the ampere rating of the panel (should be on a label somewhere on/in the panel)?  What size service do you have (100A, 150A, 200A, etc.)? What type of service is it (single phase, three phase, split phase)? Is this residential or commercial?

Comment: If I'm just assuming this is a subpanel, What size is the breaker on the main panel that this is connected to?

Comment: It looks like a 2 Phase panel box. Each breaker looks to be highly over compensated for the core size of the wires too.

Comment: Not a DIY project...

Answer (score 1):

You say an X-Ray machine? To be honest if you can afford one of those you need a certified electrical to install it. Otherwise, poof - Something will burn and insurance (assuming you got some?) is out the door!

100A machine, assuming 220Volt, that is 22Killowats typical rating! Assuming the machine runs at 220volts, it could run at 500volts or 1000volts?

**As the comments suggest its really difficult by just looking at the wires.**

My **guess** is that the central bars are separate phases on which the breakers draw power from, at 220 volts, without extra information there is no way to tell. The top left and right rails are neutral rails because they are split, but even ground/earth rails can be split and joined somewhere else. We really need to see the bigger picture here.

Because this is an commercial device, by what it looks like running in a domestic environment, the safe answer will be **No. You cannot connect the XRAY machine into that panel.**

You should find out the maximum rating of the current phase/phases you got there and or apply for a new phase if needed. But even if they are more that sub panel just simply cannot handle 100A@220Volts using those power rails, long term load could be disastrous. Typically you will need a dedicated sub panel for to supply such a device.

Comment: I think the safe answer is: no answer.  This requires an on-site professional to give this level of advice.

Comment: I think you're off by a factor of 10 in your power calculation -- 100A@220V is 22KW. Sounds hugely powerful for an x-ray machine, I wonder if it's an industrial x-ray machine.

Comment: It was late at night, and 22Kw didn't look or sound right. Sorry. Bryce. I said No in my answer. He is asking for trouble by DIY'ing this one.Its pretty obvios, isn't it? So I answered it like that. And yet I got -1 . Yaaay